# Header functions

Tags: c++, header

EDIT: by not working I mean that in my main array mA in main doesn't show any change to the elements within the array.

I have been checking my functions as I develop the headers and they have been working perfectly: Until I got to the final header `MonitorArray.h`.

> mA.getScreen(i).checkScreen();

Didn't work and I couldn't work out why. So I created a new function within `MonitorArray` to do a similar job using the same function, and to my surprise it worked.

> mA.pollScreens();

Which uses (Inside MonitorArray.h):

```
monitorArray[i].checkScreen();
```

Function getScreen:

```
ScreenArray MonitorArray::getScreen(int arrayPointer)
{
    if (arrayPointer<0 || arrayPointer>=monitors)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return monitorArray[arrayPointer];
    }
}
```

Function checkScreen and addArray:

```
void ScreenArray::checkScreen()
{
    HDC dMonitor;
    PixelArray pArray;
    int lenX = 0, lenY = 0;
    dMonitor = CreateDC(iMonitor.szDevice, iMonitor.szDevice, NULL, NULL);

    lenX = (iMonitor.rcWork.right - iMonitor.rcWork.left) - 1;
    lenY = (iMonitor.rcWork.bottom - iMonitor.rcWork.top) - 1;

    pArray.setColour(0, GetPixel(dMonitor, 0, 0));
    pArray...
    ...
    ...
    addArray(&pArray);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, dMonitor);
}

void ScreenArray::addArray(PixelArray* pA)

    {
        if (previousCheck(*pA))
        {
            arrayPosition = 0;
            screenArray[arrayPosition] = *pA;
            arrayPosition++;
        }
        else
        {
            screenArray[arrayPosition] = *pA;
            arrayPosition++;
        }

        if (arrayPosition==11)
        {
            //Run screen saver on monitor
        }
    }
```

Why does running the command within the header file through a new function work but running the functions from main not?

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Did you compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`)? Did you **use the debugger** (`gdb`)?

Comment: You'll have to be more clear on what "didn't work" means. It didn't compile?

Comment: Didn't work and I couldn't work out why
what errors you got??

Comment: Please edit your question to improve it!

Comment: You're returning a copy of the `ScreenArray` from `getScreen`, which looks dodgy to me. And I've no idea what `return false;` might do in that context. But without knowing the details of how it "doesn't work", it's impossibly to guess what might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "didn't work" means "didn't affect the `ScreenArray` in my `MonitorArray`", it's because `getScreen` returns a *copy* of the array element

```
 ScreenArray MonitorArray::getScreen(int arrayPointer)
```

while the new member function most likely works with the array directly.

You'll need to return a pointer to the array element instead:

```
ScreenArray* MonitorArray::getScreen(int arrayPointer)
{
    if (arrayPointer<0 || arrayPointer>=monitors)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        return &monitorArray[arrayPointer];
    }
}
```

(BTW: the implicit conversion from `bool` to `ScreenArray` looks very odd.)